# How to match duplicate words from a paragraph using C# or jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to match common words between two strings

```
// C# code  
string str1,str2;
```

I want to check five words in the first fifteen words of string str1

```
str1="Musician Ben Sollee on the Ravages of Coal and the Wonders of the Bicycle"
str2="There is Wonders of Musician Ben Sollee on the Ravages of Coal"
```

**I want to skip verb comparision from above strings like "of", "on", "the" etc.. only check words without verbs...**

from above strings I want to compare **str2** with **str1** if it contain five duplicate words then give message it contains some duplicate words..

How I compare it and check it contains duplicates. I am happy with either a jQuery or C# answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-liner Linq query for bonus points?

```
string[] str1Words = ...
string[] str2Words = ...
string[] dontCheck = {"of", "a", "the"};

var greaterThanFive = str1Words.Join(str2Words, s1 => s1, s2 => s2, (r1, r2) => r1)
                               .Distinct()
                               .Where(s => !dontCheck.Contains(s))
                               .Count() > 5;
```

Comment: Any .NET 3.5 language will support this. just include system.linq

Comment: Hello @ColinE, if I set strings str1Words="Official Facebook iPad App Coming Soon to the App Store Official Facebook iPad App Coming Soon to the App Store #use"; and string[] str2Words="App Coming Soon to Official Facebook iPad the Store App Official" then it returns more than 5 count..

Comment: Looking at your test strings, you have repeated words. See the updated answer, I have added a Distinct() clause. With your test data this gives 8 words in common between both strings, which is correct.

Comment: @Abhishek StackOverflow is a Q&A site, it is not a chatroom. If you want to chat, try http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 2):

Get the words from each string:

```
string[] str1Words = str1.split(" ");

string[] str2Words = str2.split(" ");
```

specify the words you dont want to check:

```
string[] dontCheck = {"of", "a", "the"}; // etc..
```

and see how many duplicates there are:

```
string[] duplicates = Array.FindAll(
    str1Words, srt1word => 
        Array.Exists(str2Words, str1Word => string.Equals(str1word, str2word)) 
        && !Array.Exists(dontCheck, dontCheckWord => string.Equals(dontCheckWord, str1Word))
);

if(duplicates.length > 5)
{
    // Give message
}
```

Comment: Hello @lockstock thanks, I want to try but Array.Contains not exist..  what will problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can Try Splitting both strings into list of words by splitting " ".
Then simply iterate over the words as specified and check if the second list contains the string.

You should also maintain a list or File with the ignored words.

```
        List<string> str1List = new List<string>(str1.Split(' '));
        List<string> str2List = new List<string>(str2.Split(' '));

        foreach (string word in str1List)
        {
            if (str2List.Contains(word))
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
```

Comment: No Problem... Guess I'm a little outdated... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
        string str1 = "Musician Ben Sollee on the Ravages of Coal and the Wonders of the Bicycle";          
        string str2="There is Wonders of Musician Ben Sollee on the Ravages of Coal";
        string[] DontCheck = new string[]{"is", "of", "the"};

        List<string> List1 = new List<string>(str1.Split(' '));
        List<string> List2 = new List<string>(str2.Split(' '));


        var Result = ((from s in List1
                       where List2.Contains(s) && !DontCheck.Contains(s)
                      select s).Count() > 5);

        if (Result)
        {
            //It Contains some duplicate words
        }
```

**Updated Code for distinct duplicate checking**

```
        string str1 = "Official Facebook iPad App Coming Soon to the App Store Official Facebook iPad";
        string str2 = "App Coming Soon to Official Facebook iPad the Store App Official App App App App";

        string[] DontCheck = new string[]{"is", "of", "the", "to"};           

        HashSet<string> Set = new HashSet<string>(new List<string>(str1.Split(' ')));
        HashSet<string> Set2 = new HashSet<string>(new List<string>(str2.Split(' ')));

        var Result = ((from s in Set
                       where Set2.Contains(s) && !DontCheck.Contains(s)
                      select s).Count() > 5);

        int result =Convert.ToInt32(Result);

        if (Result)
        {
           // It Contains more than 5 duplicate words
        }
```

Comment: @Syeda, When I tried with first fifteen words of string str1 and compare to str2 with whole string then it returns more than 5 everytime

Comment: Hello @Syeda, if I set strings str1="Official Facebook iPad App Coming Soon to the App Store Official Facebook iPad App Coming Soon to the App Store #use"; and  str2 = "App Coming Soon to Official Facebook iPad the Store App Official" then it returns more than 5 count.

Comment: Sorry @Abhishek i dont understand what are u trying to say.the string values u gave contain more than 5 duplicates..

Comment: Hello @Syeda, I got it from @ColinE. need to add .Distinct when compare results